# utf-8 codepage in webView

Tags: java, android

I try save the HTML from WebView:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> mWebViewHost.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { " +
                    "return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');})();",

            notify -> Log.d("mobileSearch", "notify->"+notify)));
```

But i have a problem: I get an incorrect HTML page. It has THE Unicode `D/mobileSearch: notify->"\u003Chtml>\u003Chead>\n      \u003Cmeta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\n          \u003Cmeta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    \u003Cmeta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n`

And if I use this code in the browser it works correctly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use encodeURI in the javascript function.

for example

```
"encodeURI(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)"
```

then use URLDecoder.

```
Log.d("mobileSearch", URLDecoder.decode(notify, "UTF-8"))
```